# magento onepage checkout manage fields

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento-1.9.1

I want to show FAX field at every checkout. Right now in magento 1.9.1 there is a functionality that if you are existing user and you are giving order two or more times then it doesn't ask you to enter address everytime but it will auto fill it from database. But I want that FAX fields should always be visible to user and if he enters value then store it otherwise it should store NULL value.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add field in checkout look [field add in checkout](http://magentoabid.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-add-custom-field-in-one-page.html).

In this link you will find jobtitle added in checkout you need to replace "job title" with "FAX".

Answer (score 0):

Magento should have a fax functionality under the customer address object.
https://www.mymagento.com/index.php/admin/customer_address_attribute/

Either enable it and toggle it to required or duplicate the phone field and set it to be fax. You may need to tweak it as desired in the frontend template used: ( vanilla: app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml )

If you're looking to force confirmation on an existing customer address entry (fax) there may be a more extensive customization you need to do.

I would explore your onepagecheckout controller that is currently used ( vanilla: app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php ) to see if any other customizations/validation is needed.